# Custom middleware in laravel for order info

Tags: laravel, middleware, laravel-middleware

So i have two sub-domains orders.domain.com and admin.domain.com

here is my web.php

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'orders.domain.com'], function()
{

    Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@index')->name('view.klientas');
        // view authenticated coupon
        Route::get('{couponcode}/view', 'App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@view')->name('view.show');
        // show coupon authenticate form
        Route::get('{couponcode}/auth','App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@show_auth')->name('show.auth');
        // handle user input, authenticate coupon
        Route::post('{couponcode}/authenticate','App\Http\Controllers\IsoreController@post_auth')->name('post.auth');
});

Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.domain.com'], function()
{
    Auth::routes([
        'register' => false, // Register Route
        'reset' => false, // Reset Password Route
        'verify' => false, // Email Verification Route
      ]);
      Route::post('/atsijungti', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@logout')->name('logout');
      Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\KuponaiController@index')->name('dashboard');
      Route::get('/kodas', 'App\Http\Controllers\KuponaiController@patvirtinimo_kodas')->name('patvirtinimo.kodas');
      
      //Prideti kuponus
      Route::get('/prideti/kuponus', 'App\Http\Controllers\KuponaiController@prideti_kupona_view')->name('prideti.view');
      Route::post('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\KuponaiController@prideti_kupona_post')->name('prideti.post');

});
```

Admin.domain.com is for creating and administrative functions like add orders and other things clients list and so on.

Clients.domain.com subdomain for clients where they will get url in there mail click it and get form where they need to write they order confirm code and there mail if coupon id in link and order confirm code with mail found in db and match then they will be redirected to the view where all order details.

The problem how check everything in middleware and don't give client access if confirm code and mail doesn't match in db. Because i can do something in controller to check but i can't restrict order view blade if someone goes directly.
P.S. confirmation code is bcrypt

Other question how limit form auth requests for one order by id like 5 bad attempts per 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For limit requests, you can use the throttle middleware.

For checking if email and coupon code exist on db or not you can create a middleware

```
class AuthenticateCouponCode {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (!CouponCode::where('coupon_code', $request-coupon_code)->where('email', $request->email)->exists()) {
            // Do redirection or thow some error to user here.
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

And then add this middleware to orders routes.

Comment: and where should i pass those requests on middleware? what should i write in my controllers